# How to identify if my website/webpage is active on a user's desktop

Tags: java, html, spring, jsp, browser

Is there any way by which I could identify whether my website is active on a user's screen or not.
I mean if he has **minimized or maximized** it.
OR
the website is in **active tab of browser**.

I am looking for something like *WindowStateListener in java*.

I want to give a note/popup etc. to user every time he comes to my site or maximizes it from taskbar or switches his browser's tab.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use onFocus in HTML to identify window is active. Sample code:

```
<script>

function onFocus(){
alert("hello, onFocus");
}

</script >

<html>
<BODY onFocus="onFocus()">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setInterval(function(){

$(window).mousemove(function(){
console.log("user is active");
});

},5000);//every five seconds you test if user still there
```

Comment: then you should keep previous width and height of the window and compare it each time when setInterval is runing

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if it's possible otherwise, but I would set a javascript timer that would count some time until we think the user might be "away". Once the time has passed we start listening to a mouseover/keypress etc event on your site and once the event occurs, alert the user.